# Porting a Ruby/Rails/MRI app to JRuby

Tags: mysql, ruby, sqlite, jruby, rbenv

I have a Ruby/Rails devvelopment environment using rbenv, MRI Ruby (1.9.2-p290), rails 3.0.9, and SQLite3. I would like to port it to JRuby, but do it such that I don't have to do anything more than run "rbenv local jruby-1.6.4" and "rails server" in the root directory of the Rails application to use it with JRuby, and "rbenv local 1.9.2-p290" and "rails serer" to use it with MRI Ruby.

I am aware that the gems to access SQLite are different for Ruby versus JRuby, but how do you write the Gemfile such that the MRI-relevant gems are picked up when the Ruby is MRI, and the JRuby-relevant gems are picked up when the Ruby is JRuby?

I will also need to port it to MySQL instead of SQLite. Which gems do I need to use here for Ruby and JRuby?

For the record, I'm using Ubuntu 11.04, Ruby 1.9.2-p290, JRuby 1.6.4, and Rails 3.0.9 or 3.0.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ported a large Rails application to JRuby last year and it was a surprising amount of work. Granted, part of it had to do with the app being rather badly written and having lots of legacy code, but still. In case you wonder: most of our problems came from gems we used, which then sometimes depended on e.g. FFI that didn't properly work with JRuby at that time. A port to Rubinius I did a little later seemed a lot less painful, but was abandoned in favor of staying with MRI.

For the Gemfile, there's a `platform` option you can use. Here's an example from the Bundler docs:

```
gem "weakling",   :platforms => :jruby
gem "ruby-debug", :platforms => :mri_18
gem "nokogiri",   :platforms => [:mri_18, :jruby]
```

It also has a block form:

```
platforms :jruby do
  gem "foo"
end
```

Either form works well, since

> All operations involving groups (bundle install, Bundler.setup,
>   Bundler.require) behave exactly the same as if any groups not matching
>   the current platform were explicitly excluded.

As a gem for MySQL I'd use the aptly named `mysql`, there seems to be a `jdbc-mysql` for JRuby.

Comment: The platforms block got me part way there. It turns out that I needed "gem 'sqlite3'" for MRI and 'gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'" for jruby. For MySQL, I needed "gem 'mysql2'" for MRI and "gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'" for jruby.