# Rails: How can my app tell if it is running in MRI or JRuby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802678/porting-a-ruby-rails-mri-app-to-jruby), I asked how to tell my Gemfile whether to take the JRuby-relevant gems or the MRI-relevant gems. The answer I got was to do the following in the Gemfile:

```
platforms :jruby do
  gem "activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter"
end

platforms :mri do
  gem "sqlite3"
end
```

Obviously, the platforms() method in Bundler knows how to figure out if I'm running MRI or JRuby. Is there another way I can tell within my program if I am running JRuby or MRI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you able to distinguish between the two like this:

```
case (RUBY_ENGINE)
when 'ruby'
  # ...
when 'jruby'
  # ...
end
```

You could write a method to give you a `jruby?` method if required:

```
def jruby?
  RUBY_ENGINE == 'jruby'
end
```

Comment: On older versions, `RUBY_ENGINE` might not be defined, so you'll need to check with `defined?`. Also, you can use `RUBY_PLATFORM`, which is defined as `java` on JRuby.

Comment: That's handy. I couldn't find a very good reference for which implementations have which constants defined.

Comment: Thanks! I eventually went with this code (in the database.yml file of my Rails app) <%= RUBY_ENGINE=="jruby" ? "mysql" : "mysql2" %>

Comment: This doesn't identify Windows. `RUBY_ENGINE` still prints `ruby`, while Bundler can tell the difference between Windows platform and others. How does Bundler know?

Comment: @Chloe Not sure without some research, but the answer is no doubt in the Bundler source.

Comment: Use `RUBY_PLATFORM` to determine the OS 'style' (not the actual OS brand and version, just Linux, Mac, Windows type OS). But `RUBY_PLATFORM` won't identify JRuby.

Answer (score 1):

With Ruby 2.2.3  `Config::CONFIG` gives me `NameError: uninitialized constant Config`, but the following works:

```
y RbConfig::CONFIG
```