# How can i find out which interpreter is being used for my ruby version "ruby 2.1.7p400" running on ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, interpreter

I have attempted

```
echo $RUBY_ENGINE

echo $RUBY_DESCRIPTION
```

both variable values are blank

Comment: try `ruby --version`

Comment: What do you mean by `interpeter`?

Comment: ruby --version outputs "ruby 2.1.7p400 (2015-08-18 revision 51632) [x86_64-linux-gnu]"

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822623/rails-how-can-my-app-tell-if-it-is-running-in-mri-or-jruby